# How do you install mutt on Mac OS X?

Tags: osx, mutt

Is there any way of installing Mutt on Mac OS X without using a compiler, homebrew or MacPorts?

Comment: So you're looking for a pre-compiled binary for OS X?

Comment: Yes, basically.

Comment: Is there a reason you're stuck w/ only pre-compiled binaries? One of the package managers will give you the option of dropping into a very Unix-esque environment any time you need to. I'm using `mutt` from Homebrew right now, and it's pretty sweet, and not even all that complicated to set up once you have a feel for *nix. I can give you the details of my setup if you'd like.

Answer (score 5):

Mutt is available as a package in the three main Package Managers for OS X:

1. [Macports](https://www.macports.org/)
2. [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh)
3. Fink

Of these Unix package managers and I am currently using HomeBrew.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally tested it, but [`pkgsrc` might work on OSX](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/platforms.html#darwin), and it has a [package for `mutt`](http://pkgsrc.se/mail/mutt).